# eMail Pivot tables created from Data Model

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a number of reports that I run in the morning.
The reports are a combination of a couple Pivot Tables that are created from the Data Model.
(They have filters for the date and team, and each day the table is a different size.)

I want to press a button and have Excel copy both Pivot Tables to an Outlook eMail.

I can get Excel to select one Pivot Table, copy it to the clipboard, open a new Outlook eMail, fill in the To: CC: and Subject field.

- I can't get it to paste.
- I can't get it to select multiple Pivot Tables.

**Things I tried:**

- [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYfhcDokArk) has some good code but it doesn't select Pivot Tables. I adjusted part of the code to be `Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")`, but it doesn't paste the pivot tables to the Outlook eMail.
- [This code that defines ranges as two variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687596/how-can-i-send-2-pivot-tables-from-two-sheets-in-an-email) - It gives me the error: "ByRef argument type mismatch". I'm assuming this is because the Function is looking to accept a Range and the selection of the Pivot Table isn't a range.

I tried `.HTMLBody = rng` but all that does is paste the Pivot Table name (PivotTable1) into the body.

I tried looking for how to turn a Pivot Table to a range with VBA. [This page](https://www.excelanytime.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=154:referencing-an-excel-pivot-table-range-using-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475) was handy to learn about `.TableRange1`, although putting
`.HTMLBody = rng.TableRange1`
or defining rng as.
`Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").TableRange1`
only brings up the error

> Type Mismatch

- [This page explains Range.PivotTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pivottable), but if I `Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range.PivotTables("PivotTable1")` it gives me the error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"
- [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51504639/sending-daily-email-from-excel-to-outlook-include-pivottable) has a fixed range
- [This video](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel%20vba%20copy%20and%20paste%20pivot%20table%20to%20email%20body&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTg5vzrsjhAhWo3eAKHaZPC9YQBQgrKAA&biw=1275&bih=605#kpvalbx=1) goes into copying to a new workbook then creating an .html file before putting it into Outlook. This seems overly complicated. I'm hoping for a more elegant solution before going this far.
- I tried recording a macro, selecting the Pivot Table, copying, pasting to Outlook. It gave me:
  `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True`
  `Selection.Copy`
  So when I do:
  `.HTMLBody = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DVS1").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True`
  I get the error "Expected: end of statement" and it highlights `""` in the above.
- I tried amending `.select` to the end of `rng.Select` and `Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").Select` with the suggestion [from this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383894/vba-select-pivot-table), but I get the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

I can't remember what page it was on, but someone mentioned their code won't work for Pivot Tables that were created using the Data Model. [This was a close match](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_o365b/vba-code-to-paste-data-from-a-pivot-table-to-an/04f834a1-46df-41bd-94f0-1c983faf091a), but he mentions that the table size will never change (so that won't work for me).